# GET [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] when using " pip install " with Docker container

Tags: docker, pip, ssl-certificate

I'm new to Docker.

Here are the steps I did with docker

1. I use a "docker pull python" command to get a python images
2. I created a python container---docker run -it python:3.7.4 /bin/bash
3. I'm trying to pip install something in the python container.
4. THEN, GET a "SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" ERROR Message, and I'm confused why.

by the way,I am using a company network. the company network is under a proxy.

The problem stop me for 1 day and I'm Exhausted.

Is anyone know this stuff and give me a answer, thanks

[![here is a picture help you to understand what I am talking here][1]][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwOQo.jpg

Comment: I solved this by add proxy settings with -e: docker run -e http_proxy=http:/xxxx:xxxx@10.xx.xx.xx:1008 -e https_proxy=http://xxxx:xxxxx@10.xx.xx.xx:1008 -it --name=name python:3.6.5 /bin/bash